# Does Windows Server 2012 R2 Come With A Proxy Serer?

Tags: networking, proxy, windows-server-2012-r2, open-source

I'm doing a test project in an attempt to learn how proxy servers work within the Windows 2012 Server R2 environment. Is there a built-in solution within the software itself? If not, what are some good open-source alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what type of proxy you need, I can only assume it's about forward or reverse web proxy.

Apache httpd has Windows version available and it offers both of the aforementioned features.

Comment: I believe it's forward proxy that I want

Comment: @sadpandabunny: You need to *know* what type of proxy you need. Otherwise, your question is not answerable.

Comment: @Sven ok, I need a forward proxy

Comment: So, given that, you can try with Apache httpd. If you ever change your mind and require a reverse proxy solution, switch to Apache httpd. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need something like ISA 2003/6 or Forefront TMG.